# How to keep the hyperlinks, in table column, clickable when sending to body of mail?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, outlook

I am trying to send an email via Outlook using VBA.

I have a column filled with hyperlinks. When the email is constructed, the hyperlinks turns into plain text and are not clickable.

I reference the column using Cells(row_num,1) because all the hyperlinks are unique.

How to make them show up as hyperlinks?

```vb
Sub SendEmail()

Dim olook As Outlook.Application
Dim omailitem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim i As Byte, row_num As Byte
row_num = 2

Set olook = New Outlook.Application

For i = 1 To 15

    Set omailitem = olook.CreateItem(0)

    With omailitem

        .To = Sheets(1).Cells(row_num, 2)
        .Subject = "Tool Notification"

        .Body = "Hello!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Below are the link(s) to the task(s) that you have due on: " & _
          Cells(row_num, 4).Value & _
          vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Link: " & Cells(row_num, 1).Value & _
          vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you," & _
          vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Tool"

        .Display

    End With

    row_num = row_num + 1

Next

End Sub
```

**Sample Data**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Stx.png

Comment: Check [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5849-excel-vba-insert-hyperlink-into-email-body.html)

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I have seen this. My situation is different because all of the rows in my hyperlink column are different. I don't have just one static hyperlink that I need to insert in my body, which is why I used Cells(row_num,1).Value. Hyperlink tasks are different depending on email recipient.

Comment: Your code creates one mail item for each row. is that correct? posting some sample data would help

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Correct, for every item in Column B, that individual will get an email. That email should include the Hyperlink in Column A. I posted a picture of sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

This should be pasted in a standard module.

**EDIT:** Adjusted to accumulate links by sender

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendEmail()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Dim lastRow As Long

    Dim recipientAddr As String
    Dim bodyContent As String
    Dim duedateFormat As String
    Dim linkFormat As String

    ' Set reference to target Sheet (replace 1 with the sheet's name or codename)
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    ' Find last cell in column b
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Set target range
    Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

    ' Start new outlook instance
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    ' Loop through each cell in column B
    For Each cell In targetRange.Cells

        ' If cell has data
        If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then

            ' Check if is the same recipient as next
            If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then

                linkFormat = linkFormat & "<a href=" & Chr(34) & cell.Offset(0, -1) & Chr(34) & ">" & cell.Offset(0, -1) & "</a><br>"

            Else

                linkFormat = linkFormat & "<a href=" & Chr(34) & cell.Offset(0, -1) & Chr(34) & ">" & cell.Offset(0, -1) & "</a>"

                ' Collect email data from cells
                recipientAddr = cell.Value
                duedateFormat = Format(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value, "mm-dd-yyyy")


                ' Build the link string
                bodyContent = "Hello!<br><br>" & _
                              "Below are the link(s) to the task(s) that you have due on: " & duedateFormat & "<br><br>" & _
                              "Link(s): <br>" & _
                              linkFormat & "<br><br>" & _
                              "Thank you,<br><br>" & _
                              "Tool"

                ' Create the mail item and display it
                Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

                With olMail

                    .To = cell.Value
                    .Subject = "Tool Notification"
                    .HTMLBody = bodyContent

                    .Display

                End With

                ' Reset the link
                linkFormat = vbNullString

            End If

        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: What would the loop look like, for when I have the same email address appear in Column B, they receive one email with all the associated links in Column A? For instance, in my picture, (pc239) would receive two separate emails with one link in each. I would like to capture all links for (pc239) to get one email.

Comment: Semi works! For instance, (pc239) receives 1 email with two links like mentioned. However, if (pc239) shows up later down the Column after other addresses, then another email will be created for (pc239). If the name isn't right after one another, then multiple emails are still created for one address.

Comment: Actually, found a solution. I sorted that column first then ran the code. It works! Thank you